# Filter by "Created by" is not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, filter

I have created a list view that filters documents on "Created by" column. Users within my organization are able to see the information correctly.

However, users who are logging via external account(like hotmail, gmail etc...) are able to login to the site and can upload documents. But they are able to see other documents as well. The filter is basically not working for external users.

The site I'm using is an external facing site

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to restrict external users from seeing internal documents, or do you just want to filter the documents - but there's really no harm if they see anything else? I'm trying to understand if this is a permission question or a filter question. It's two different things.

Comment: I just want users to see only the documents they uploaded

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the [Me] filter to get your created by filter to work. And that’s OK if you’re using external user who have an account in your authentication provider such as Active Directory (AD). Then the simple solution would be like this:

[image]

But I guess that’s not the case here. I guess you have invited users through sharing you’re site to external users without giving them an account in your AD. What happens then is that you’re phasing two different patterns of user accounts.

Your internal users follow the pattern `domain\user`, which SharePoint can resolve as a user and filter by. Your external users have a different user ID pattern which SharePoint can’t resolve and as a consequence can’t filter. When the filter fails, the result is that all documents are shown instead of only those for the external user.

In SharePoint Online/Office 365 the pattern for external user is `<external e-mail address>#EXT#@<www.your-company.com>` which differs from `domain\user` in SharePoint.